# Print really long webpages to PDF Safari or Chrome -- any quick solution?

Tags: safari, macos

I have tried using Safari and Chrome to print really long webpages to PDF and both of them take awfully long... When I export the webpage to html and open it in TextEdit, it loads fine and even the Export to PDF is really fast...but the formatting isn't pretty with TextEdit's Print to PDF. Safari WebContent is processing really slowly and I wanted to ask if there is any other solution for printing awfully long webpages into pdfs quickly...

Comment: No. TextEdit loads quickly because it doesn't process everything. Safari or Chrome will give you the full webpage,  but they must process every single item on it and convert it to a PDF. Just let your computer run and do its thing.

Comment: Well, I saw that the one produced by TextEdit is about 15500 pages! I kept Safari running for 3:53 hours and I had to force quit Safari Web Content and I couldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I use a free program called paparazzi https://derailer.org/paparazzi/
It will make log web pages in to a single pdf or Jpg of the appropriate size.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try it and see if it works out for me! Btw, the one produced by TextEdit is about 15500 pages!